# Form closed event

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to keep the form. When the "No" button pressed in the following code.

```
private void parent_window_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Logout!", 
        "Log Conformation.", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else if(result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        //How to keep the form here!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: FormClosed cannot be canceled, it tells you that the window is gone so that's too late.  You must use FormClosing instead, don't forget to pay attention to e.CloseReason.  The user is already sure he wants to quit btw, no need to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code in a Form Closing event and add `e.Cancel = true` in the else if statement for NO

You are to use a Form Closing event because Form Closed is thrown when the form is already closed and you cannot stop an already closed form from closing.

```
else if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```